# Multiple Realm queries for different Objects

Tags: swift, polymorphism, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I want to create an entire database search that returns an object of type `Results<A>`. I have a class `A` that inherits from a Realm `Object` and then a lot of other classes that inherit from that subclass. Something like this:

```
class A: Object {}
protocol Z {}
class B: A, Z {}
class C: A, Z {}
class D: A, Z {}
...
```

Now I want to query different classes at the same time and I'm doing something like this:

```
private func getResults<T: A>(withTypes types: [T.Type]) {
  for type in types {
    let foundIds = getRealm().objects(type).filter(aPredicate)
    ids.append(contentsOf: foundIds)
  }

  // Do something with all those ids
}
```

And I'm calling it like this:

```
getResults(withTypes: [B.self, C.self, D.self])
```

The problem is that Realm does not like polymorphism and as soon as I add more than one class type inside the array when calling the function it crashes because the inferred type of the array is `A.self` instead of the individual element in each position of the array. The filtering is done by using a `Z` protocol variable that `A` does not conform -and it shouldn't- but the rest of object do conform it. So this works:

```
getResults(withTypes: [C.self])
```

or this:

```
getResults(withTypes: [D.self])
```

Because the inferred type of the `Array` is `C.self` or `D.self` and not the generic inferred `A.self`.

I want to point out that in the database there is not any `A` object, it's just the superclass of all the other objects.

How can I create that multiple search?

I've thought that I could create a kind of searchable object and query it but the database that I manage is huge and I do not know if that would create a big impact on the system's performance.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In your query, if you are only interested in getting the ids and appending them to an Array, you can map them `ids.append(contentsOf: foundIds.map({ $0.idFromZProtocol }))`. But this will disable the lazy loading of Realm because all objects will be visited.

What you can also do is doing the other way:

- Let's say A is Animal, B is Dog, C is Bird, D is cat.
- You are looking for all the green animals.

You can have

```
Animal
@objc dynamic var dog: Dog?
@objc dynamic var bird: Bird?
@objc dynamic var cat: Cat?

Bird, Cat, Dog
@objc dynamic var color: String
@objc dynamic var legNumber: Int

let predicate = "dog.color == Green || bird.color == Green || cat.color == Green"
getRealm().objects(Animal.self).filter(predicate)
```

And you can have a processed variable on Animal to know if it's a cat or dog or bird by checking which variable isn't nil. You can also assign your Z protocol to Dog, Cat and Bird in order to do `Animal.color` instead of guessing `Animal.dog?.color` or `Animal.cat?.color` etc

With this approach, you can keep the lazy loading feature of Realm which is nice if you have a very big Realm file.

Comment: Unfortunately that wouldn't be an optimal solution because I have more than 50 different subclasses of `A` and, as I said, `A` is not being stored in the database. So even if I had that structure inside `A` -dirty in my opinion-, I wouldn't be able to search for that specific object because it does not exist. If I had to store `A` to be able to do that, I could create a `Search` entity to use to search that would contain the `id` of the Realm objects that I want to search among. So I'd be storing a new object, `Search` instead of `A`, and I'd avoid creating all those variables inside `A`.

Comment: Oh I missed that part where A isn't in DB. Well in this case, it's not possible. You need to rethink your DB schema by doing something similar to what I propose for example (which is CPU-efficient). It might be dirty and that's why you need to create a top-layer that cleans it and only use that top-layer. Or you have to do all the processing by hand fetching individually all objects and merging by hand. It can't be a Result (which is a map to Realm DB directly, so A need to be there), but will be a fully-loaded Array.

Comment: Yes I see... maybe the best approach is what you say. Saving `A` to the database and make it extend the protocol and avoid creating all those vars in `A`.

Comment: You can always go for SQLite which might be more what you are looking for in terms of schema.

Comment: We already have a really big product and changing that would take us a lot of money we cannot waste on this... But thanks for your help :)